# My sql query using node js does not display the query result in hbs view, and i have used this method else where in the code

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

const userName = req.body.userNames;
const password = req.body.password;

```
con.query("SELECT * FROM users where email = ? AND password = ?", [userName, password], function(err, collections){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        if(collections != 0){
            res.render('userProfile', {collections: collections})
            console.log(collections);
    }
    else{
        res.jason("Incorrect password or Account does not exist, check your login again.. Thank you");
    }
}
});
```

And here is my handle bars view < li class = "nav-item dropdown header-img-icon" >


 < div class = "dropdown-menu" >




{{#each collections}}

{{collections.fullName}}

{{collections.email}}

{{/each}}

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't include `collections` as part of the Handlebars view when referencing the child variables:

```
{{#each collections}}
  {{fullName}}
  {{email}}
{{/each}}
```

Also, I don't think the `if(collections != 0)` code is doing what you expect:

```
if(collections.length > 0) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: okay i get i now, since its a single record there isnt a need to loop empty fields. Thank you it worked

Comment: Please mark as accepted, if it solves your question.